# how to get folder names within a sub folder in sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

list.RootFolder.SubFolders[i] gives folder/subfolder name
can anyone help me on how to get folder names within a  subfolder in sharepoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any sample code or can you show us a code sample of what has been tried to date?

It will help to answer your question if you can provide more information or tell us more about what you've tried or even post code which you have tried which you're having a specific problem with.

---

However, based on what I think you're after I'll try and provide a response....

One thing to watch out for is that `list.RootFolder.SubFolder[i]` actually returns you another [`SPFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415075.aspx) object. So you could access the `SubFolders` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.subfolders%28v=office.14%29.aspx) again to get the sub-folders within that sub-folder.

This is going to be a bit of a naive example, but something like:

```
SPFolder subFolder = list.RootFolder.SubFolder[i];
SPFolderCollection subFoldersOfSubFolder = subFolder.SubFolders;

if (subFoldersOfSubFolder.Count > 0)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < subFoldersOfSubFolder.Count; j++)
    {
        SPFolder specificSubFolder = subFoldersOfSubFolder[j];
        /*
            At this point you could use properties like Name, 
            ServerRelativeUrl or UniqueId of the SubFolder class to get 
            the information you need.
        */
    }
}
else
{
    //If you get to here, it means that the sub-folder had no sub-folders
}
```